# Why does this simple android app gets crash after using ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I wrote a android app to understand the concept of ListView.

The MainActivity.java file is  :

```
package com.example.swasik.firstday;

import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String Age[] = {"11","222","33","44444","551"};
    String City[] = {"Pune","Delhi","Chennai","Kolkata"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        AutoCompleteTextView a = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,Age);
        a.setAdapter(adapter);

        ListView b = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        ArrayAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, City);
        b.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
}
```

The activity_main.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.swasik.firstday.MainActivity">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        >

    </ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The AndroidManifest.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.swasik.firstday">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

On running the app on mobile is displays the message : "Unfortunately App has stopped" How to fix this?

The logcat file shows :

```
04-17 22:50:21.794 1576-1576/com.example.swasik.firstday E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                                               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
                                                                               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465)
                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602)
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118)
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423)
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2006)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1245)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1420)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1138)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4645)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
                                                                               at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 
                                                                               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2465) 
                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250) 
                                                                               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1162) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598) 
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:602) 
                                                                               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:415) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598) 
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118) 
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598) 
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118) 
                                                                               at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598) 
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118) 
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598) 
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118) 
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396) 
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681) 
                                                                               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598) 
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5118) 
                                                                               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2423) 
                                                                               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15598) 
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2006) 
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1245) 
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1420) 
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1138) 
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4645) 
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725) 
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555) 
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525) 
                                                                               at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:174) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4952) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794) 
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
04-17 22:50:30.614 1576-1576/com.example.swasik.firstday I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1576 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post crash log

Comment: ArrayAdapter requires a TexxtView but you are providing AutoCompleteTextview. For that you have to use custom adapter

Comment: Change `activity_list_item` to `simple_list_item_1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this will solve your problem:

```
ArrayAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, City);
```

Answer (score 1):

ArrayAdapter expects that the layout resource you provided contains a TextView as its root element, otherwise it does not know how to bind the data to the view. If you want to specify a more complex layout, use the constructor that takes both a layout resource and the id of a TextView within that layout:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
        R.layout.activity_list_item, R.id.some_textview, City);
```

Moving forward, you may find that your data becomes more complicated and that ArrayAdapter is simply not enough to accomplish what you want. At that point you should consider writing your own ListAdapter class. I would refer you to an old video called [The World Of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKpoCampbMAhVM7GMKHcvdAz4QtwIIJTAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DwDBM6wVEO70&usg=AFQjCNF5_lMTBUGWJz4gD4HgimG5qv4KBQ&sig2=O5kgTmPGCzhCnIkyXRU_Fw) that covers the fundamentals of LIstViews. (Also at some point you should consider using RecyclerView instead of ListView).

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayAdapter<> constructor you are using isn't providing a TextView that it needs.  Try using the following constructor instead.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, android.R.id.text1, Age);
```